# Redirect in Shell (C)

Tags: c, shell

I'm trying to write a simple shell, it all works except the redirect with '>'. I was advised to parse my input string from the user using a delimiter of ">". The output string then has two elements, output[0] will be the entire command that user enters including the arguments. output[1] will be the filename.

My issue is that it creates the file specified by output[1], however it writes nothing to it! Even if I put a printf to stdout, it writes to the terminal instead.

```
                        else if(*delim == '>'){
                            int f = open(output_str[1], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666);
                            int stdout_sv = dup(1); // Saving the current stdout descriptor for restoring later.
                            if(errno != 0){
                                    perror("");
                            }
                            dup2(f,1);
                            execvp(output_str[0], output_str);

                            printf("Sample Line to file.");
                            dup2(stdout_sv, 1); // Restoring stdout
                            close(f);
                    }
```

This results in the following output:

```
[04/04 15:55]# ls > test.txt
output_str[0] = ls 
output_str[1] =  test.txt
Sample Line to file.[04/04 15:55]#
```

I'm really confused as to why the stdout isn't being redirected towards the output file(test.txt). I mean the output file is correct.

Note: I realise there is a space before test.txt, I have tried parsing with " >" which removes the space in the output_str[1], the file still ends up empty.

Comment: Buffering is the source of the problem. Flush the buffer for stdout before restoring its underlying file descriptor to `stdout_sv`. Alternatively you may be able to use `write` for unbuffered output.

Comment: I will try that now. Is my execvp() arguments okay?

Comment: Okay. It's now writing "Sample Line to file" however the actual command output isn't being written to the file. I'm skeptical of my arguments

Comment: I can't see enough code to verify that your args are what you want them to be. I can say that I don't think it's going to do what you ultimately want it to do. As it is written, and assuming `output_str` is as described, it looks like `ls` will only list the output filename, in this case `test.txt`. If that's what you expect and it's not working, then I would definitely check the contents of your `output_str` array.

Comment: I've printed the output_str in the output in the question. I have been told to keep output_str[0] = ENTIRE COMMAND incl/ arguments. And output_str[1] = filename. That's exactly the output I'm getting but it's resulting in the execvp not being executed.

Comment: I will also add that you should not expect to get the sample line output if execvp is working. It replaces the current executable and does not continue the processing of your code if successful. If this is not what is desired, you may want to `fork`.

Comment: Doesn't sound right to me. the **vp** part of `execvp` means that it searches the path for the first argument (the executable to run) and that it accepts a null-terminated vector (array) of pointers with the args (including the executable) as the second argument. For example, if you wanted to run `ls -la` you would call `execvp(args[0], args)` where `args` looks like `["ls", "-la", 0]`.

Comment: I seemed to have solved it! Thanks for the help! I needed to use strtok() once again after the entire string as parsed.

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved it!